# 'Limit INT OFFSET @variable' throw runtime error in mysql server

Tags: query, limits, offset-fetch

I'm trying to solve [this problem in Hackerrand](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-20/problem?isFullScreen=false)

The problem asks for the median in a specific column

my code:

```
SET @VAE = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STATION);
SET @VAE1 = ROUND(@VAE/2)-1;
SELECT LAT_N FROM STATION ORDER BY LAT_N LIMIT @VAE1;
```

But I get syntax error.

When I write the query as following it runs ok, but I don't want it in such way

```
SET @VAE = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STATION);
SET @VAE1 = ROUND(@VAE/2)-1;
SELECT LAT_N FROM STATION ORDER BY LAT_N LIMIT 5;
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score -1):

[image: Use procedure to execute]
we cannot use the variables in normal offset in limit but we can use variables in procedure